# Hide all elements after a specific element

Tags: javascript

I need to hide all elements on a Wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogs_in_warfare) after an element with the id of "See_also" using javascript. Any suggestions on how to do this quickly? I think I'm overcomplicating my possible solutions.

Comment: are you using juery ?

Comment: No, this actually needs to be Vinella JS, or else this would be much easier

Comment: Please see https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt and https://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Vanilla JS Solution

Keep on removing the sibling elements until you reach the end.

```
const span = document.getElementById("See_also");
const h1 = span.parentElement;
let nextEl = h1.nextElementSibling;
while (nextEl) {
  nextEl.style.display = "none";
  nextEl = nextEl.nextElementSibling;
}
document.getElementById("catlinks").style.display = "none";
```

Comment: @Glitchin Please check if this solves your problem, you can copy paste this code on Wikipedia's console and check if you're getting the desired results. Do let me know if you  have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

If the elements after "See_also" are on the same level in the hierarchy , you can achieve this in CSS like so:

```
#See_also ~ * {
    display: none;
}
```